# Is there a way to use material displacement information to create a weight map?

Tags: materials, weight-painting, displacement, vertex-groups, procedural

I'm using material displacement to make a mountain range and I was wondering if there's a way to use the displacement information to drive a hair particle system (for trees) because I'm trying to keep everything as procedurally generated as possible.

My first thought was to turn the values of the displacement into a weight map but I can't figure out how to do it. If anyone knows a way, or a better way of doing this, it'd be much appreciated. :)

Here's the material displacement I want to use as a weight map:
[image: material displacement I want to use as a weight map]

Comment: You mean a procedural (no image) displacement, using a displacement shader?

Comment: Yes, and to use that data for a weight map

Comment: You'd have to bake the height to an image texture, first, I think. (in which case you may as well use it for the other things) Would that screw your whole procedural workflow?

Comment: Ah right thanks. Yes I was hoping there'd be a way for the displacement info to directly drive the weight map so it could be 100% procedural but I guess that's not possible. Thanks anyway!